# How to install PostGIS shp2pgsql-gui on openSUSE 13.2?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, linux, pgadmin-3, shp2pgsql

I installed PostgreSQL 9.4.4 together with pgAdmin III (1.20.00) and the PostGIS extension (2.1.7, via the Stack Builder) from http://www.enterprisedb.com/products-services-training/pgdownload on my openSUSE 13.2 (32 bit) machine.

Unfortunately, the GUI of the Shapefile-Loader (shp2pgsql-gui) has not been installed. After endless Google queries and reading similar questions here, I gave up and hope that I can get a helping hand here.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: No sorry, I wasn't successful